EF Core, Unidirectional many-to-many relationship
I have an entity setup like this:
public class Mission {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ApplicationUser? Auditor { get; set; }
    public string? AuditorId
}

In this setup, each Mission can have 0 or 1 Auditor, and we don't care about going the other way (finding the missions associated with an auditor)
I wish to change it to this:
public class Mission {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public ICollection<ApplicationUser> Auditor { get; set; }
}

So that each Mission instead has any number of Auditor, and again I don't care about going the other way.
But when I edit the Mission entity like this and generate a migration with EF Core, the migration contains this:
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "mission_id",
                table: "AspNetUsers",
                type: "integer",
                nullable: true);

The migration is adding a Column "mission_id" in the AspNetUsers table, but that cannot be correct because each user is potentially linked to multiple missions, and anyway I don't care about this side of the relationship so I'd rather not have it.
The problem is that I don't know how to correct the migration or how to generate a correct one for my use case ... (because there's also the ModelSnapshot that I would need to change)
Edit
I found this section of documentation which seems like what I want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#unidirectional-many-to-many
But it doesn't even compile ? this syntax public List<Tag> Tags { get; } = []; seems incorrect
Edit 2
Actually the syntax was correct (Rider linter wasn't), but the generated migration is still wrong !

about your last edit and the compilation issue, what .NET version / C# language version are you using ?

My target framework is net8.0 and EntityFrameworkCore is set to 8.0.3

You need C# version 12 or higher (this is the error message I get for instance on dotnetfiddle if using .NET framework 4). If using .NET 8.0 then you should be able to change the C# language version in project or solution settings.

public List<Tag> Tags { get; } = []; is C# 12. It should work in .NET 8.

aaah very confusing, Rider was incorrectly telling me it was wrong but it did compile actually

Then you should check if your Rider needs updating: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2023/12/07/rider-2023-3-release/

I'm updating it right now, my original problem unfortunately remains though :(
but thank you for your help

I was missing the other part shown in the documentation:
builder.Entity<Mission>().HasMany(m => m.Auditors).WithMany();

adding this in OnModelCreating() and re-generating the migration worked !
